# Pass a class as a parameter?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I have been lead to believe that it is possible to pass a class as a method parameter, but I'm having trouble implementing the concept. Right now I have something like:

```
- (id)navControllerFromView:(Class *)viewControllerClass
                          title:(NSString *)title
                      imageName:(NSString *)imageName
{
    viewControllerClass *viewController = [[viewControllerClass alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *thisNavController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController];

    thisNavController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle: title
                                          image: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]
                                            tag: 3];
    return thisNavController;
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
rootNavController = [ self navControllerFromView:RootViewController
    title:@"Contact"
    imageName:@"my_info.png"
];
```

What's wrong with this picture?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> ```
> - (id)navControllerFromView:(Class)viewControllerClass
> ```

It's just `Class`, without the asterisk. (`Class` isn't a class name; you're not passing a pointer to an instance of the `Class` class, you're passing the class itself.)

> ```
> rootNavController = [ self navControllerFromView:RootViewController
> ```

You can't pass a bare class name around like this—you have to send it a message. If you actually want to pass the class somewhere, you need to send it the `class` message. Thus:

```
rootNavController = [self navControllerFromView:[RootViewController class]
                                          title:@"Contact"
                                      imageName:@"my_info.png"
];
```

Comment: I see now - everything you said makes sense - and it works if I use "id viewController = [ [ viewControllerClass alloc ] init ];" - but I get a "viewController undeclaired" error if I try "viewControllerClass *viewController = [ [ viewControllerClass alloc ] init ];" Any idea why? Or can I not use the class parameter like that?

Comment: Correct. You need the name of a class there. Remember, compile time and run time are separate things; the object in the viewControllerClass variable isn't known until run time, so you can't use it to statically declare an object variable at compile time. You have to use “id viewController”.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you've almost got it. You want to pass `[RootViewController class]` instead of `RootViewController`. That gives you a `Class` value. Also, I don't think you want your function to take a `Class *`, just a `Class`. It's not actually an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained any problem with the code you've posted. What doesn't work? What are you expecting to happen? The only thing I can think of so far is that you might want to pass `[RootViewController class]` instead of just `RootViewController`. Also, your formatting is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
func acceptingFunction(aClass: AnyClass) {
    ... 
}
```

call with:

```
acceptingFunction(UIView)
```